# changing image src doesn't work when there is srcset

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 product-image">
        <img width="295" height="982" src="http://localhost/2017/ltru/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/IMG_8576-copy-1.png" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="http://localhost/2017/ltru/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/IMG_8576-copy-2.png 295w, http://localhost/2017/ltru/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/IMG_8576-copy-2-90x300.png 90w" sizes="(max-width: 295px) 100vw, 295px"> </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <h4 class="ltru-underline ltru-inline">Product 4</h4>
        <p></p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p></p>
        <div class="product-thumbs">
            <a href="http://localhost/2017/ltru/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/IMG_8576-copy-1.png">
                <img src="http://localhost/2017/ltru/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/IMG_8576-copy-1.png" alt="">
            </a>
            <a href="http://localhost/2017/ltru/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/IMG_8576-copy-2.png">
                <img src="http://localhost/2017/ltru/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/IMG_8576-copy-2.png" alt="">
            </a>
            <a href="http://localhost/2017/ltru/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/IMG_8576-copy-3.png">
                <img src="http://localhost/2017/ltru/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/IMG_8576-copy-3.png" alt="">
            </a>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and I am trying to change `.product-image img` `src` attribute with the following js:

```
$('.product-thumbs a').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var src = $(this).attr('href');
        var main_img = $(this).closest('.product-detail').find('.product-image img');

        main_img.attr('src', src);
});
```

I can see from the JS console the `.product-image img` `src` is changing when I click on the product thumbs, but the image doesn't change. Is `srcset` causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change `srcset` attribute as well as `src` attribute:

```
$('.product-thumbs a').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var src = $(this).attr('href');
        var main_img = $(this).closest('.product-detail').find('.product-image img');

        main_img.attr('src', src);
        main_img.attr('srcset', src); // <-- changing srcset attribute
});
```

Comment: Ah ok, changing `srcset` too fix the problem. But I think I am gonna remove that attribute for now. thank you @Alexander Reznikov

Comment: You are welcome. Please vote for my answer, if it was useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `img` selection is not correct. Actually `.product-image img` will give you all images in `.product-image` along with your thumbs so use `>` in between `.product-image img` try

```
var main_img = $(this).closest('.product-detail')
           .find('.product-image > img'); // now it will give you a single object and src will be applied to that one only.
```

A better option can be, use class name of that `img` so that it would be easy to get that image only like,

```
var main_img = $(this).closest('.product-detail')
           .find('.product-image img.wp-post-image'); // no need to use > in this case
```

Comment: thank you for addition `img.wp-post-image`, I think it will make the script works faster, aint it?

Comment: Yes, you need not to worry about other images and it will only affect src to that image only.